Selectively Pushing Content from One Git Branch to Another
I’m currently managing a GitHub repository with two branches: main and obsidian-vault. The main branch hosts all the necessary files for my website, while obsidian-vault is used specifically for drafting blog posts.
In obsidian-vault, there's a folder named "Publish" where I finalize blog posts. I need to selectively move content from this "Publish" folder to the main branch without merging the entire branch.
I'm looking for any advice on how to streamline this process or if there’s a better approach to selectively pushing changes between branches in Git.
Thanks in advance!
Here's what I've tried so far:

Committing Changes in obsidian-vault: I commit all changes made to the "Publish" folder.
Cherry-Picking to main: I switch to the main branch and attempt to cherry-pick these commits so that only the changes from the "Publish" folder are brought over.

I'm getting lots of errors along the way, and none of them make sense to me since I'm not an expert on this. I've tried working with ChatGPT on that, but it's becoming more confusing and annoying than helpful.

"I'm getting lots of errors along the way" but you didn't paste any here. What exactly do they say?

I've managed to make it work.
# Step 1: Check out to main branch
git checkout main

# Step 2: Use the checkout command to move the "Publish" folder
git checkout obsidian-vault -- Publish/

# Step 3: Add and commit the changes
git add Publish/
git commit -m "Add content from Publish folder in obsidian-vault"

# Step 4: Push the changes to the remote repository
git push origin main

